# Como criar script que permite pendrive no Windows pelo Serial Number?

Tags: script, powershell

Gostaria de trocar com os senhores algumas ideias práticas para realizar um feito:
Criar um script para Windows que verifique o Serial Number de um pendrive e possa assim permitir ou negar que ele monte:

Até o momento, tenho o seguinte:

```
     #CAPTURA SERIAL NUMBER
                    
        $serial = ((Get-Physicaldisk|Select SerialNumber,BusType|findstr /L USB)| %{"$($_.Split('USB'))"})
               
         #CONSULTA SE O SERIAL FOI CADASTRADO NO SISTEMA
       iwr http://FORMULARIO_WEB_COM_SERIAIS_DE_PENDRIVES_CADASTRADOS.html -OutFile C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\serie.txt
                
                    
ForEach ($value in $serial){
                    
                     
 $compara = (Select-String -Path C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\serie.txt “[$value]” -Quiet)
                 
$value
$compara
                
        if ($compara = "True"){
                
                        reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR /v Start /t REG_DWORD /D 3 /f
                    }
        else{
                
                        reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR /v Start /t REG_DWORD /D 4 /f
                
                    }
            
            }
```

O arquivo serie.txt contém strings com número de séries dos discos permitidos e a medida que é atualizado no formulário WEB continuamente, vai atualizando a lista.

No script acima, a variável $compara deveria fazer a comparação do serial do dispositivo conectado via USB e então dar o valor True ou False. Porém ela só dá True, mesmo o valor da String do serial não estando no arquivo serie.txt.

Se eu faço

```
Select-String -Path C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\serie.txt “123456” -Quiet
```

e "123456" está no arquivo serie.txt, o valor remetido é True!

E aí pessoal o que me sugerem?

Comment: Para evitar discussão muito longa nos comentários a conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128533/) e pode prosseguir pelo link fornecido. Sobre a pergunta, pode [edit] e fornecer um [mcve] da parte com problemas para reconsideração da postagem.  Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).